# How to get nth div's child element value using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the value of 4th div's child input element. 
Basically im getting checked chekbox value and would like to add the associated input box value using "this"keyword
Here is my html code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="cell-checkbox" style="float:left;margin-right:5%;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="select" value="7" class="big">
    </div>
    <div class="cell-desc" style="float:left;margin-right:5%;width:30%;">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
    <div class="cell-cart"> //input box is inside this div
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        <table align="center" class="cellBuy">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr align="right">
                                    <td width="1%">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="buyid" id="buyid" value="7">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="category" value="464">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="itemid" value="">
                                        <input name="qty" id="qty" size="6" maxlength="6" value="1" class="input"> /*want to get this input text value
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    <td height="20">
                                        <div align="left">
                                            <input type="button" class="btn-BuyOff" value="Buy" id="addtocart" name="addtocart">
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried the below mentioned code but its not working

```
var result = [];
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {
    result.push($(this).val() + "," + $(this).parent().next().find('#qty').val());// this is for finding quantity field value
});
var strreuslt = result.join(';');
alert(strreuslt);
```

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with `id="qty"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using closest to get the closest parent that contains both inputs and than trigger the find

```
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {
    result.push($(this).val() + "," + $(this).closest('.container').find('input[name="qty"]').val());
});
```

or:

```
  $(':checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {
        result.push($(this).val() + "," + $(this).parent().siblings('.cell-cart').find('input[name="qty"]').val());
    });
```

Note: if you have multiple groups of inputs you will need to wrap each group in a dom element preferably `ul li`

Answer (score 2):

`$(':checkbox').eq(3)`
This gives you 4th element in jquery. Indexing starts from zero, so .eq(3) will give 4th child.

Comment: i want to get value something like this $(this).parent().next().find('#qty').val());

Comment: #qty is Id and it is unique for entire page so you don't need to traverse through complex query instead you get result by $('#qty').val()

Comment: @ Mantas Čekanauskas .eq(4) will give 5th child not the 4th. 4th child will be given by eq(3). Indexing starts from 0.

Comment: @Yogita088 you are absolutely right, zero based index sometimes can be confusing ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have issue with dom traversing. `$(this).parent()` do not return div having input checkbox element in it. You should rather traverse to closest div with class container and then find input checkbox in it. Like this:

```
var result = [];
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {
 result.push($(this).val() + "," + $(this).closest('.container').find('[name="qty"]').val());// this is for finding quantity field value
});
var strreuslt = result.join(';');
alert(strreuslt);
```

Comment: i want to get value something like this $(this).parent().next().find('#qty').val());

Answer (score 1):

Use `name` instead, and never use same `id` for multiple elements:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.cell-cart').find('[name=qty]').val();
```

Or use this if container contain multiple `<div class="cell-cart">`:

```
$(this).parent().next().next().find('[name=qty]').val();
```